# Issue with unscrewing tripod head

Tags: tripod, tripod-heads, manfrotto

I recently purchased a Manfrotto tripod with tripod head. I'm not sure if it's me or not, but I'm unable to unscrew the head from the top of the tripod. I keep unscrewing it and it never comes out. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Check the bottom, there's usually one or more small set screws also used to secure the head.

Comment: What specific model Manfrotto tripod and what specific head?

Comment: Manfrotto 055CXPRO3 with Manfrotto 498RC2 Ball Head.

Comment: Was the head already attached to the tripod when you bought it?

Comment: If the head is not locked in position, lock it to allow it to be unscrewed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a picture of the underside of that plate on my 055XPROB connected to an 804RC2 3-way head -

[image: 055XPROB Base plate]

You can see a slot headed screw thread here and there are 2 more that need to be slackened to release the head (in this case an 804RC2).  Also when you unscrew it you may need to turn the silver plates, not the top of the head.

Answer (score 3):

There are three small set screws recessed in the bottom of the plate at the top of your tripod. You must back them off enough to allow the base of the ball head to be rotated. Be sure the middle shaft of the tripod is tightened or you might be rotating the entire shaft. And grip the base of the ball head below the "ball".